# Listening requests to mysql with wireshark. 127.0.0.1 is fine, but requests to localhost are ignored

Tags: mysql, networking, wireshark

I'm trying to debug requests to mysql server with wireshark on linux. In wireshark I'm listening to all interfaces with filter mysql. When I connect to server like:

```
$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 ...
```

then wireshark dumps requests, but if

```
$ mysql -h localhost ...
```

then requests are ignored by wireshark (table remains empty).

in /etc/hosts : 127.0.0.1   localhost

What the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the host name is literally `localhost`, the client library uses UNIX domain sockets instead of TCP/IP.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html:

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to `localhost`, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a [`--port` or `-P`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html#option_general_port) option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use [`--host` or `-h`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html#option_general_host) to specify a host name value of `127.0.0.1`, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for `localhost`, by using the [`--protocol=TCP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol) option.